# Can't install TP-link Archer T4U V3 driver on 19.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, 19.04

I have an Archer T4U Wi-Fi adapter but I can't install the drivers. Could someone please help me?

`lsusb` gives out this result:

```
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 2357:0115 TP-Link
```

When I try to compile it with `make`, the following error shows up:

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.0.0-27-generic/build M=/home/alvaro/rtl8822bu modules
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-27-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/alvaro/rtl8822bu/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/alvaro/rtl8822bu/include/osdep_service.h:41,
                 from /home/alvaro/rtl8822bu/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/alvaro/rtl8822bu/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/alvaro/rtl8822bu/include/osdep_service_linux.h: In function ‘_init_timer’:
/home/alvaro/rtl8822bu/include/osdep_service_linux.h:257:8: error: ‘_timer’ {aka ‘struct timer_list’} has no member named ‘data’
  ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
        ^~
/home/alvaro/rtl8822bu/include/osdep_service_linux.h:258:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  init_timer(ptimer);
  ^~~~~~~~~~
  _init_timer
In file included from /home/alvaro/rtl8822bu/include/drv_types.h:35,
                 from /home/alvaro/rtl8822bu/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/alvaro/rtl8822bu/include/wifi.h: At top level:
/home/alvaro/rtl8822bu/include/wifi.h:1005: warning: "IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF" redefined
 #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF 0x40
 
In file included from /home/alvaro/rtl8822bu/include/osdep_service_linux.h:84,
                 from /home/alvaro/rtl8822bu/include/osdep_service.h:41,
                 from /home/alvaro/rtl8822bu/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/alvaro/rtl8822bu/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
./include/linux/ieee80211.h:1444: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF  0x100
 
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:286: /home/alvaro/rtl8822bu/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1606: _module_/home/alvaro/rtl8822bu] Error 2
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-27-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:1318: modules] Error 2
```

Comment: Please insert the device and run the terminal command: `lsusb` Next, edit your question to show the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @alvaromz i know this thread is 2 months old but if you're still having the issue with your RTL8822BU adapter, you could try installing drivers as I have described in here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1179178/928088 I too have the same adapter and I just installed in Ubuntu MATE 19.04 running kernel 5.3.4, and the adapter is working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this USB Wifi Card is based on Realtek RLT8822BU Chipset.

On support page I only see "outdated" drivers [T4U V3 180511](https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201806/20180619/Archer%20T4U(EUUS)_V3_180511_Linux.zip) and [T4U V3 181018 Beta](https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201810/20181018/Archer%20T4U_V3_181018_Linux_beta.zip), may they work, may not.

I would try to use driver from https://github.com/brandon-bailey/rtl8822bu and compile it.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/brandon-bailey/rtl8822bu.git
cd rtl8822bu
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8822bu
```

Comment: I can confirm the https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu version works on the latest Kubuntu that I just installed and updated today (over a wire). The https://github.com/brandon-bailey/rtl8822bu did not compile. USB: Bus 004 Device 002: ID 2357:0115 TP-Link Archer T4U ver.3

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try

https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu

```
cd rtl88x2bu
VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Comment: This worked really well for my archer T4U, when nothing else did, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Works with kernel head v5.3.xxx using this repo. which you will need to git clone into a local folder

https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu

```
git clone https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu
```

Make sure you have `build-essentials` and `dkms`

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms
```

After cloning, `cd` into that folder and run

```
cd rtl8822bu
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Then connect to your Wi-Fi (Hopefully, both 2.4GHz and 5GHz should be detectable now)

Next, follow these steps to refine the installation and for an automatic rebuild on Ubuntu kernel image updates

```
sudo dkms add .
sudo dkms install -m 88x2bu -v 1.1
```