# Help! on installing TP-link AC13000 T4U V3 driver on 18.04 without Internet connection and without dkms package installed?

Tags: 18.04, drivers, gcc, dkms, tp-link

I am having bad trouble. I bought TP-link AC13000 T4U V3 and try to use it with ubuntu 18.04 (Linux version 5.3.0-40 with gcc 7.4.0). However, I cannot gain any Internet connection from my Desktop at all.

It only accepted a wired connection, but unfortunately, I am stuck in an apartment that only allows me to access the Wireless connection. So far, I have tried some solutions:

Soln. 1 [How to install TP-LINK Archer T4U driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802205/how-to-install-tp-link-archer-t4u-driver)

Soln. 2 [Ubuntu 18.04.1 and TP-Link Archer T4U(EU) v2.0 nightmare (RTL8812AU chipset)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067513/ubuntu-18-04-1-and-tp-link-archer-t4ueu-v2-0-nightmare-rtl8812au-chipset)

For these 2 solutions, nothing works after typing  **sudo make finish**, nor I get any error.

So, I tried the second solution of this post:

[Can't install TP-link Archer T4U V3 driver on 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164054/cant-install-tp-link-archer-t4u-v3-driver-on-19-04)

Then, it seems that my computer reacts to

> sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}

Then as I typed the next line, I realized that my ubuntu 18.04 also doesn't have **dkms** package.

1. So, could you please recommend the source that I should use for installing **dkms**? By this, I mean which link should I use to manually download and then copy the package from my laptop that can access the Internet to my desktop.
2. Also, which **source of the TP-link driver** and installation command is really working?
3. Lastly, do I also need to consider **downgrading GCC version?** I just saw the installation manual of the TP-link AC13000 T4U V3, which said that the working GCC version is 4.7.

[Edit 1.] These solutions might not match the version of TP-Link, nor my OS exactly.  I tried them because I could not find the right one, but if you know that there is a better option then, please that would be great.

[Edit 2.] This is the output from **lsusb**

[image]

Comment: The links above provide different drivers for different chipsets. It will be useless to install the wrong driver. Before we proceed further, let's identify your exact device. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: The driver 88x2bu is correct for your 2357:0115 device, not any others. I will be writing an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news! You can get the driver installed and working temporarily without dkms.

Please download this file and transfer it to the desktop of your Ubuntu machine: https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu/archive/5.6.1_30362.20181109_COEX20180928-6a6a.zip

Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' A new folder will be created called rtl88x2bu-5.6.1_30362.20181109_COEX20180928-6a6a. Open a terminal and do:

```
cd ~/Desktop/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1_30362.20181109_COEX20180928-6a6a
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Now do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms
```

Ignore the many updates that will be offered.

Once dkms is installed, do:

```
sudo make uninstall
sudo modprobe -r 88x2bu
VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

You should be all set. Now install the updates:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt -Y upgrade
```

Comment: Hi @chili555... This is promising!  I am actually replying to you from the computer. The wireless is now working!!!!!!  
There is only a few steps left: "sudo apt install git dkms" gives me an error  E: Package 'dkms' has no installation candidate. Could you please suggest me what to do?

Comment: Please open Software and Updates and under the Ubuntu Software tab, be certain that *at least* main and universe are selected. After making any changes at all, again run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install dkms`

Comment: Thanks.... Yes I can install it now... Everything seems to work fine at the moment. Thanks so much !!!!!!.

Comment: Awesome! If my answer has been helpful,please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: Yes, I accept this answer. What should I do to technically accept your answer?

Comment: I believe you will see a checkmark to click next to my answer that indicates that you've accepted it as "works for me!" Please click it.

Comment: Sorry.....  I see.... :)

Answer (score 1):

if you have a android smart phone .. go into settings / about phone . then find build number and tap on the build number... this unlocks developer options.. a new menu .. and now back up in settings and locate the new developer menu and in it enable USB debugging .
.
now use your data/charge wire connected to the phone and computer .. you should get a notification ..tap it for usb options and  select tether . 
.
now the computer should be able to get on your mobile data ,or wifi the phone is connected to ... confirm this by openning the browseer then head to any familiar page .. if it loads you are good .. close it .. and 
.
option 1
run the software and updates utility ,being sure to enabble Canical partners in the 2nd menu .. and click the Additional drivers menu.  try to x the update out and it will prompt a refresh and reveal the driver... (usually ) if a new driver option pops up concerning ethernet drivers ..give it a try.. u may find other drivers for nvidia (if you have a nvidia GPU )

optionaly .. if you are not terrified of the teriminal .. press Ctl+Alt+T to open a terminal ... annd enter commmands one line at a time followed by enter 
.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

.

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
```

.
.
the second line will update the kernal

.
chheck the ethernet/wifi menu .. if your card shows up you are golden
.
  if you dcide to add any other wifi cards or usb wifi devices ..include linux in your search terms at amazon google,or ebay.. there are several that work as plug n play on linux ( depends on devices internal chipset model.. ) if u have 2 working you can connect both to diffent wifi routers or use one for a personal hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the `build-essentials` and `dkms` packages are installed on your Ubuntu distro, you will not need an Internet connection. 
The alternative, if you do not have any of the packages, you can get `build-essentials`, `dkms`, and `https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu` in a thumb drive and install it on your machine via https://askubuntu.com/a/334163/771386

Here, are the detailed steps in case you have a wired ethernet that works on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with kernel head v5.3.xxx using this repo. which you will need to git clone into a local folder

https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu

```
git clone https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu
```

Make sure you have `build-essentials` and `dkms`

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms
```

After cloning, `cd` into that folder and run

```
cd rtl8822bu
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Then connect to your Wi-Fi (Hopefully, both 2.4GHz and 5GHz should be detectable now)

Next, follow these steps to refine the installation and for an automatic rebuild on Ubuntu kernel image updates

```
sudo dkms add .
sudo dkms install -m 88x2bu -v 1.1
```